# Nodejs Express with pm2 deploy outside localhost

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I have a Nodejs Express project working fine on localhost with pm2. The question is how can I generate a domain or alias for my IP to deploy the server visible to the world (I'm looking a free solution, not interested in hosting solutions). I need to do this on windows.

Comment: I'd encourage you to read the [help]. It has a lot of great information about the guidelines of this site. Under those guidelines this question is actually considered too broad for this site.

Comment: well I think that is a very specific question about pm2 config running on windows. I didn't found anything about this. I don't know if it's possible without paid methods. I am not looking for an explanation either. Any link to a documentation that serves me. But  ok no problem

Comment: This question doesn’t even really relate to Node, PM2, or windows at all. It could also be argued that it’s considered off topic for this site since it looks like you are looking for off site resources.

Comment: If it has nothing to do with these technologies, it could be that it I'm more lost than I imagine. I know external host methods and I understand how they work. From what I see they tend to be quite dependent on the type of technology. My logic tells me that if they can do what I say, anyone could. Pm2 is supposed to be for that. In all the documentation of pm2 there is talk of deployments to production, however there is no documentation about it. I don't think I'm breaking any rule or that I deserve those negative points, but I could be wrong.

Comment: No idea if this is allowed on Stack Overflow. But in my profile I have a link to a contact page. Shoot me an email and I’ll try to help out. Not gonna help here since this question is for sure not following the Stack Overflow guidelines.

Comment: ok, every help will be acepted.

Answer (score 3):

if this is just for development purpose try using [localtunnel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/localtunnel)

Comment: Hi thanks, but in this case is for production, but I'll keep localtunnel for development